# What is the quick load achievement in Alien Swarm?

Tags: achievements, alien-swarm

Today, after 3 hours of game, I gained

> **Quick Load**
>   - Successfully perform a fast reload.

but I really didn't understand what it is and how I got it. Can you explain me what to "perform a fast reload" means?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When reloading a gun, there's a meter in the bottom left corner. Inside the meter there is a small grey rectangle. If you press your reload key a second time while the white bar is inside the grey rectangle, you will reload in double quick time (and work towards the relevant achievements).

[image: Alien Swarm Quick Reload Bar]

You may find it helps to move the reload bar much closer to your character by changing the following cvar: `asw_fast_reload_under_marine 1`.

You'll have come across this before if you've ever played Gears of War.

Comment: +1 for the tip about moving the reload bar. I find it annoying that it's in the lower left corner.  Thanks a ton for that!

Comment: The cursor also has a (albiet hidden) reload bar too, you've just got to look closely.

Comment: can you write where to add the cvar? On the console?